# Ionic 5, ngModel not work as excepted on array model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i'm using ionic 5 and angular, i tried to use ion-checkbox and the model target is an array:

```
user_id: any = [] // the model to target
user: any // data that filled from request api to be use on ngFor
```

on my html i use it like this:

```html
<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user_id" value="{{ user.id }}"></ion-checkbox>
```

but this make the all checkbox checked and unchecked at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check-box works differently. each control has it's name and value:

```js
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      demo: '',
      itemOne: '',
      itemTwo: '',
      itemThree: '',
    });
```

```html
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label floating>Placeholder Input</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" formControlName="demo"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Checkbox Item</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="itemOne" [checked]="checkMe"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Checkbox Item</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="itemTwo" checked="false"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Checkbox Item</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox formControlName="itemThree" [checked]="false"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-checkbox?file=pages%2Fform-example%2Fform-example.html)

Here is an example to create dynamic list of checkboxes: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-checkbox-setting-values-and-using-as-an-array/87118/2

Comment: i've tried to bind the checked attribut with conditional value, the checked value change but the behavior of the checkbox have some late behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738355/ionic-5-ionic-checkbox-so-late-behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

`<ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="user_id" [checked]="user.id"></ion-checkbox>`